# Bundling javascript files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bundle, gulp, browserify

I have a project where different modules are written as closure functions (Example of this module is shown below). I am trying to optimize the project, can anybody help me with bundling suggestion? like how do I bundle them to a single file?

1. I know requirejs but these are traditional closure functions and I am not sure if I can use requirejs as this project is not written in commonjs or AMD pattern?
2. other option I found was to concat all these JS files but as per the forums this is not a good practice.

Can anybody suggest me the correct way for bundling these kind of files? or was that a wrong way to write modules at the first?

```
 var main = (function(){
    //constructor
    function main(){};

    main.prototype.entry = function(){
        alert("entry function called");
    }
    return main;
})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to keep this structure then concatenating them is likely your own option.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for your comment. I have an option for changing application to AMD structure, is it a good idea to change to  AMD pattern or commonjs pattern? your suggestion please.

Comment: If you want to be future proof, changing it to ES6 modules would probably be the best solution: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html. There are tools which can transpile this to any other module system of your choice.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for your quick response and for your suggestion. Appreciate it!